# Why last div in my webpage has different heights on computer and phone?

Tags: css, height

I make this webpage http://imaginary.freeasphost.net/Instruments/

Last div element has bottom border below buttons, when I open this page on computer. I have Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

When I open in on phone Xiaomi Redmi 8, bottom border is above buttons and they leak from section. I have Firefox, Chrome and Mi Browser. I checked it on other phones and internet friends checked it too, on different phones and there is same problem on all phones. Div has different heights on computer and phone.

I tried to change box-sizing, from border-box, to padding box and content-box and used moz and webkit css properties and it did not help.

Here is how it looks on computer and how I want that it looks: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmz3e.png)

And here is how it looks like on phone: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdGXU.jpg)

EDIT: Is there browser for windows that behaves like browser on phone, so that I do not have to always upload page to check how it looks like on phone? I know that chrome, firefox etc have developer tools where I can check how it will look on phone, but in this case everything looks good there, but on real phone css behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

On line 1029, change height to min-height. That should fix it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).